# Tor browser logging in problems

Tags: security, tor

When I use **Tor Browser**
I always have a problem with login With many web pages such as Facebook or any other service such as *Proton* service's
The error message usually says that the password or email is wrong, but I used another browser on the same device and succeeded in logging

I thought it might be a **bridge** problem, but really not.
Because the bridge I use is a reliable bridge and almost no other works in my country, *Egypt*.
The bridge is **obfs4** and I am on the latest *version* of Tor